# I need an NSMutableDictionary, where the values will be arrays, that will be created while the app is running, and filled up later

Tags: ios, xcode, nsmutabledictionary

So at runtime I initialize my `NSMutableDictionary`, and then when the user clicks on certain buttons, the app needs to get the name of this button and this name will be the key. Then he will click on another button, and this button's name will be put into an array, and the array will become the value of the first button name's key. However, later the user will keep doing this, and if he ends up clicking on a button that already is a value in the dictionary, then the second button he presses must be added to the array already associated with that key. Here is my code so far.

`closestBeaconsDictionary` is the main dictionary. `closestBeaconName` is a variable that makes up the keys, and `pinNumberName` is the value that must be put into an array. closestBeaconName and pinNumberName are constantly changing based on what buttons the user presses.

```
//first, check to see if the key already exists. If not, then add the key to
//closestBeaconsDictionary and then create an array and add this array to the dictionary
//and then add pinNumberName to this array.
if ([closestBeaconsDictionary objectForKey:pinNumberName] == nil)
    {
        NSMutableArray *closestPinsToBeacon = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        [closestPinsToBeacon addObject:pinNumberName];
        [closestBeaconsDictionary setObject:closestPinsToBeacon forKey:closestBeaconName];
    }
else
    {
        //what do I do here?? How do I access the dictionary that is at key:pinNumberName 
        //and then add an object to it?
    }
```

So, my question is basically what do I put in the else statement? I'm confused because isn't `closestPinsToBeacon` basically destroyed after the block of code runs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
if ([closestBeaconsDictionary objectForKey:pinNumberName] == nil)
{
    NSMutableArray *closestPinsToBeacon = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [closestPinsToBeacon addObject:pinNumberName];
    [closestBeaconsDictionary setObject:closestPinsToBeacon forKey:closestBeaconName];
}
else
{
      NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
      arr = [[closestBeaconsDictionary objectForKey: closestBeaconName] mutableCopy];
      [arr addObject:pinNumberName];
      [closestBeaconsDictionary removeObjectForKey: closestBeaconName];
      [closestBeaconsDictionary setObject:arr forKey: closestBeaconName];
}
```

Hope this helps.. :)

Comment: Worked! I didn't even have to edit it haha, great job.